# header restrictions with XHR

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

does XMLHTTPRequest allow one to set "any" headers? Because it seems to be limiting me from setting the host header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, as it will cause security issues. Please refer to [W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-setrequestheader-method), the setRequestHeader() method should terminate if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:

- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Cookie
- Cookie2
- Content-Transfer-Encoding
- Date
- Expect
- Host
- Keep-Alive
- Origin
- Referer
- TE
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding
- Upgrade
- User-Agent
- Via

Update: Konstantinos Filios is right that latest list can be found in [WHATWG XMLHttprequest spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).

Comment: The link should be updated because work on the referenced document has been discontinued as of 18 Nov 2014.

Here's the new URL with the list of forbidden header names: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name